# Embedding html in php unexpected <' error

Tags: php, html, embed

I am new to php, but I can't figure out what the problem is.  I am trying to make a text box for string entry.

```
<?php
$file = fopen("/file/location","r");
while(!feof($file)){
    echo fgets($file);
    echo "<br>";
}
fclose($file);
<html>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Car Loan">
    </form>
</html> 
echo $_GET['subject'];
<html> file_put_contents("/file/location", $_GET['subject'], FILE_APPEND); </html>
?>
```

The first part runs fine, but when I get to the `<html>` it starts to spit out all sorts of errors.

Comment: you're injecting pure HTML into php here.

Comment: Plus, you should be getting an undefined index notice.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comments, you're injecting pure HTML into PHP.

You have to close off the PHP tag, then reopen.

The `<html>` tag in this `<html> file_put_contents` and related `</html>` needs to be removed also.

There should probably be a trailing slash for `/file/location` if that gives you a problem, but might not be needed, it's just a side note here.

```
<?php   
    $file = fopen("/file/location","r");
    while(!feof($file)){
    echo fgets($file);
    echo "<br>";
    }
fclose($file);
?>

    <html>
            <form name="form" action="" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Car Loan">
            </form>
    </html> 

<?php 
    echo $_GET['subject'];
    file_put_contents("/file/location", $_GET['subject'], FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

However, you need to use a conditional statement here, since you will get an undefined index notice for the echo'd GET array and in the `file_put_contents` seeing that your entire code is in the same file; `action=""` suggests it. [Error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) will help you here.

I.e.: `if(!empty($var)){...}` and/or `if(isset($var)){...}`.

Make sure also that the folder can be written to and that proper permissions have been set for it.

Your folder declaration might also require it to be a full server path.

Consult the manual on `fopen()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php.

I.e.: `fopen("/var/usr/public_html/file/location","r");`.

The same might also happen for [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). If what you have now gives you a problem, try a server path instead.

**Footnote:**

You could place the closing `</html>` after

```
file_put_contents("/file/location", $_GET['subject'], FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

since echoing something outside the HTML tags will throw something in the console/HTML source.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing html with php without properly enclosing.
Here's an edited version:

```
<?php       
    $file = fopen("/file/location","r");
    while(!feof($file)){
        echo fgets($file);
        echo "<br>";
    } 
    fclose($file); 
?>
<html>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
       <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Car Loan">
    </form>
</html>  
<?php
    echo $_GET['subject'] . file_put_contents("/file/location", $_GET['subject'], FILE_APPEND); 
 ?>
```

Comment: That will still throw undefined index notices.